# JAWBONE NERD dongle => Normal dongle

Tags: bluetooth, programming, encoding

I have a JAWBONE NERD DONGLE which is specifically connectable to Jawbone Icon. I'm trying to find a way to turn this into a normal dongle. I am not asking you to make the program; just please tell me how to change the internal program of this dongle. I have tried the ways I know, but there was no way to look into the codes inside this dongle. I would really be thankful if you simply tell me which programs to download to fiddle and code this dongle.

Answer (score 2):

It most likely contains a write disabled chip inside.

So you won’t be able to change it.